# How to Configure Nginx on ec2 public instance/NAT instance and django server on private instance?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I want to configure my nginx server on ec2 public instance i.e. a Nat instance also. and my django server is running on private instance. I am not able to call django server through nginx.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I changed the proxy_pass and it is working now. but i am not able to access static files from private instance. Do i need to add "proxy_pass" in location /static/?

Comment: Please post your config.

Comment: server {
  listen       YYYY;
  server_name  X.X.X.X;
  location / {
     proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
     proxy_redirect     off;
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header   X-Scheme         $scheme;
     proxy_pass         http://app_server;
     proxy_intercept_errors on;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }
  location /static/ {
     proxy_pass  http://app_server;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     root     /opt/site/mysite/static;
     try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ @app_server;
  }